# How to IsReadOnly change in cell in datagrid in wpf using mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

My Grid as follows.

What i want is When click on checkbox in datagrid if checked True Holoday Name Should be Enable or Else it should editable.

```html
<DataGrid CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Name="dgwCalenderDetails" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding CalenderDetails, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="770">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Day Id" Binding="{Binding DayId}" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="False" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Day" Binding="{Binding DayName}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding DisplayDate, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" Width="75" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Time" Binding="{Binding StartTime, StringFormat=N2}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Working Hours" Binding="{Binding NoOfWorkingHrs, StringFormat=N2}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="Holiday Status" Binding="{Binding IsHolidayYN}" Width="100" CanUserReorder="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Holoday Name" Binding="{Binding HolidayName}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHolidayYN}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HolidayName}" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsHolidayYN}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind a property to IsReadOnly property of your column. Handle to checkbox checked event and update your property that you bind to column in event

Answer (score 0):

Make in your viewModel cellEditEnding event and inside check the state of the checkboxColumn. If it is selected, that find column and set to true; Something like:

```
public void CellEditEndingEvent(object Sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{  
    if(String.Equals(e.Column.Header.ToString(), "YourCheckBoxFieldName")
    {
        var x = e.Row.Item as YourType;
        if(null != x)
        {
            e.EditingElement.IsEnabled = x.IsHolidayYN;
        }
    }            
}
```

To get this method in viewModel use interactivity and interactions libraries. And I did not test code.